# Weblogic 12c, Spring boot transaction rollback not working with rollbackFor

Tags: spring, transactions

I have written a sample application with Spring boot and JPA. I am using spring transaction management. I have 2 inserted 2 records and after that have deliberately thrown Exception and used @Transactional(rollbackFor =Exception.class). It works fine in tomcat, whole transaction is rollbacked as expected.

But this doesn't work with weblogic server. It persist 2 records. Is there any solution to this ? I want to rollback my complete transaction.

```
   class A{
      @Transactional(rollbackFor =Exception.class)
      public void b(){
        save(object1);
        save(object2);
        throw new Exception();
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to define a jdni in your weblogic, then define in your **application.properties** spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/oracle where **jdbc/oracle** is the jdni defined in the weblogic.

it worked for me